# How to list all zsh autocompletions?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh, tab-completion, zsh-completion

In zsh, I'm trying to get an idea of which commands have an existing completion so that I can write completions for commands that don't.

Is there a way to list the commands that zsh will complete without grepping the completion files? For instance, is there a built-in command that will list them?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The list of known completions is stored in the associative array `_comps`. The command names and other completion contexts are used as keys for `_comps`, while the corresponding completion functions are stored as values.

You can get a full list of commands with associated completions with the following command:

```
for command completion in ${(kv)_comps:#-*(-|-,*)}
do
    printf "%-32s %s\n" $command $completion
done | sort
```

#### Explanation:

- `for command completion in LIST; COMMAND` takes iterates over `LIST` while taking two elements, `command` and `completion`, on every iteration and running `COMMAND` for them. This is also a short form of the `for`-loop that does not require `do` and `done`.
- `${(kv)ASSOC_ARRAY}` expands the associative array `ASSOC_ARRAY` to a space separated list of key-value pairs. So it is an alternating list of "key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3 …", which is taken up by the two arguments of the `for`-loop. `$ASSOC_ARRAY` would only expand to a list of values.
- `${ASSOC_ARRAY:#PATTERN}` filters out all elements of `ASSOC_ARRAY` from its expansion, where the key matches `PATTERN`.
- The pattern `-*(-|-,*)` matches the names of all special contexts, like `-math-`, `-parameter-` or `-value-,NAME,COMMAND`. It would also filter any command name that either matches `-*-` or `-*-,*`, should such a command have a completion on your system. (You could just leave out the pattern filter to be sure)
- `printf "%-32s %s\n" $command $completion` does a formatted output so that you get a nice table. `$command` is printed in place of `%-32s`, padded to 32 characters with left-alignment (`-`). `$completion` is printed in place of `%s`.
- `| sort`: associative arrays are unordered, so output of the loop needs to be run through `sort` in order to get a ordered list.

Comment: What do the `key` and `value` signify here?

Comment: @Adaephon what do you call `${(kv)ASSOC_ARRAY}` this type of syntax where you have the parentheses and some letters inside it `(kv)` ? do you have a good reference for it i can read up on ? thanks